# window.onload and AJAX and Complete Page Loaded

Tags: javascript

I have been reading around, and i know that window.onload, document.onload and body.onload are similar, yet can cause instances at differing times during the pages load sequence.

I have a problem where the page itself is rendering fine, it loads, the event handler fires, but it cannot do its thing because an AJAX call has not completed within the body of the document.

I am trying to automatically read all the textareas in a document.  These dont appear until after the AJAX is called.  This is a site wide requirement.

Can you in anyway check a document after its window, document, body and all the AJAX is completed.  Will i need to write a onCompleteAll into my AJAX classes. A bit of a pain todo, because some AJAX calls step into other AJAX calls and theres no telling how many will run on any given page.

Comment: You should use a system of "pooling" for your ajax request: kind of an array containing all running ajax request. You add new request in the pool in `beforeSend` callback and you remove it in `complete` callback. Then you'll need a mecanism to check when the array becomes empty: an implementation of an observable array is a solution, take a look to KnockoutJS.

Comment: i have an count that runs.  it spits out logs to show there is 1 of 5, 2 of 5 running  1 of 5 completed, 2 of 5 completed.  Although this is only a count with var active, and var complete.  Ill look into it, i havent stacked any requests. I suppose i could do an if (active == complete).